# Spring Boot Handling of X-Forwarded-Host Header

Tags: nginx, spring-webflux, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am working with a Spring Boot 3 service that uses `spring-boot-starter-webflux`.  This service contains a simple endpoint:

```
@RestController
public class TestController {

    @GetMapping("/test")
    public String test() {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

Suppose I run this service on port 8080.  I can curl this endpoint as follows and get a HTTP 200 response:

```
% curl -v -H "X-Forwarded-Host: localhost" http://localhost:8080/test
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8080...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /test HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.86.0
> Accept: */*
> X-Forwarded-Host: localhost
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
< Content-Length: 4
<
test%
```

But if I craft a request to this endpoint using a value for `X-Forwarded-Host` that contains a `:<port>`, I get a HTTP 400 response:

```
% curl -v -H "X-Forwarded-Host: localhost:8080" http://localhost:8080/test
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8080...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /test HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.86.0
> Accept: */*
> X-Forwarded-Host: localhost:8080
>
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< content-length: 0
<
```

There appears to be an issue with the `X-Forwarded-Host` header containing a port number in it.

Questions:

1. Can the `X-Forwarded-Host` header contain a `:<port>`, or should it just contain a hostname / IP?  Documentation for `X-Forwarded-Host` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Forwarded-Host) appears to indicate that it's just a hostname, however the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Host) for the `Host` header indicates that `<host>:<port>` is allowable (and in cases where a nonstandard port is used such as here, it's actually *required*).  There is also a `X-Forwarded-Port` header, which for some reason my reverse proxy is setting to `80`.
2. To resolve this issue: is this a bug in Spring Boot?  Or is this a configuration issue with my reverse proxy (nginx 1.21.6) not setting the `X-Forwarded-*` headers correctly?

Comment: The workaround for my root issue for now is to run my `nginx` reverse proxy on port 80/443.  This way, the `X-Forwarded-Host` header value does not contain `:8080`

Comment: Please enable spring security DEBUG logs and post the full logs here

Comment: Also, your function returns`void` but yet somehow you can return the string `”test”` from it.

Comment: Has nothing to do with Spring Security.  I don't have Spring Security as a dependency.

Comment: Sorry mixed the tags up, i meant the spring boot debug logs